# Don't understand a PDE argument involving $L^p$ norms and inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm reading [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.7219v1.pdf).
I do not understand how the author proves Corollary 5.12 for the case $p=2$. He addresses everything except $p=2$ but claims it holds for all $p$. Can someone help me to see why it is true?

[image]

He uses Proposition 5.9, which I quote here.
[image]

Here is the weak form of the equation. Choosing the test function to be $u$, I almost get the identity (5.36) for $p=2$ but the $\delta$ term is wrong. 
[image]

Comment: Looks like a mix-up on the authors' part; I suggest emailing them. The case $p=2$ could be obtained as the limit $p\nearrow 2$, since the constants in the inequality do not depend on $p$ (it seems). But the gap between $2$ and $3$ remains completely unexplained.